# Gradient Descent is Diverging

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I am following Andrew Ng's Coursera course and I am trying to write a basic python implementation of gradient descent using the housing data that I believe he also used in the slides (it can be found [here](https://github.com/girishkuniyal/Predict-housing-prices-in-Portland/blob/master/ex1data2.txt)). I am not using numpy or scikit learn or anything and I am just trying to get code working with a 1D input and output with a line of the form `theta0 + theta1 * x` (2 variables). My code is very simple but yet even if I increase or decrease the learning rate or let it run for more iterations, it still manages to diverge. I have looked over and tried multiple other formulas and it still diverges. I have made sure the data loads up properly. Here is the code:

```
dataset_f = open("housing_prices.csv", "r")

dataset = dataset_f.read().split("\n")

xs = []
ys = []

for line in dataset:
    split = line.split(",")
    xs.append(int(split[0]))
    ys.append(int(split[2]))

m = float(len(xs))

learning_rate = 1e-5

theta0 = 0
theta1 = 0

n_steps = 1


def converged():
    return n_steps > 1000


while not converged():
    print("Step #" + str(n_steps))
    print("θ Naught: {}".format(theta0))
    print("θ One: {}".format(theta1))

    theta0_gradient = (1.0 / m) * sum([(theta0 + theta1 * xs[i] - ys[i]) for i in range(int(m))])
    theta1_gradient = (1.0 / m) * sum([(theta0 + theta1 * xs[i] - ys[i]) * xs[i] for i in range(int(m))])

    theta0_temp = theta0 - learning_rate * theta0_gradient
    theta1_temp = theta1 - learning_rate * theta1_gradient

    theta0 = theta0_temp
    theta1 = theta1_temp

    n_steps += 1

print(theta0)
print(theta1)
```

Theta naught and one very quickly become `nan` because they go to infinity. What I did notice is that both theta naught and one oscillate between positive and negative and get increasingly bigger. For example:

```
Step #1
θ Naught: 0
θ One: 0

Step #2
θ Naught: 3.4041265957446813
θ One: 7642.091281914894

Step #3
θ Naught: -146.0856377478662
θ One: -337844.5760108272

Step #4
θ Naught: 6616.511688310662
θ One: 15281052.424862152

Step #5
θ Naught: -299105.2400554526
θ One: -690824180.132845

Step #6
θ Naught: 13522088.241560074
θ One: 31231058614.54401

Step #7
θ Naught: -611311852.8608981
θ One: -1411905961438.4395

Step #8
θ Naught: 27636426469.18927
θ One: 63829999475126.086

Step #9
θ Naught: -1249398426624.6619
θ One: -2885651696197370.0

Step #10
θ Naught: 56483294981582.41
θ One: 1.304556757051869e+17

Step #11
θ Naught: -2553518992810967.5
θ One: -5.89769144561785e+18

Step #12
θ Naught: 1.1544048994968486e+17
θ One: 2.6662515218056607e+20

Step #13
θ Naught: -5.218879028251596e+18
θ One: -1.2053694641507752e+22
```

Comment: Have you checked your gradient computation against a finite difference implementation?

Comment: @Julien No. My biggest point of confusion is that I have checked the code over many times at it perfectly matches both the formula (given online and in the courses course) and with others code that they have posted on the internet (as tutorials, not questions) so I am wondering why mine doesn't work

Comment: How about you first do so then? Also it's hard to help without sharing the loss function you use, and maybe you should output that loss at every iteration too: there is no absolute reason why theta should not diverge (if you SGD on loss=1/x, x will diverge), if your loss decreases, then your SGD works, and the problem may lie in the data and/or your choice of loss function.

Comment: I'll add in loss and see if it decreases, but I would expect it would increase as thetas are getting so massive

Answer (score 1):

I've gotten your code working with some minor changes. Ignore the imports I have, that was purely for my own plotting purposes.  This one should use your new dataset.  The main change was simply adjusting the learning rates and removing a few unnecessary casts.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

dataset_f = open("actual_housing_prices.csv", "r")

dataset = dataset_f.read().split("\n")

xs = []
ys = []

for line in dataset:
    split = line.split(",")
    xs.append(int(split[0]))
    ys.append(int(split[2]))

m = len(xs)

learning_rate1 = 1e-7
learning_rate2 = 1e-3

theta0 = 0
theta1 = 0

n_steps = 1


def converged():
    return n_steps > 100000


while not converged():
    print("Step #" + str(n_steps))
    print("Theta Naught: {}".format(theta0))
    print("Theta One: {}".format(theta1))

    theta0_gradient = (1.0 / m) * sum([theta0 + theta1*xs[i] - ys[i] for i in range(m)])
    theta1_gradient = (1.0 / m) * sum([(theta0 + theta1*xs[i] - ys[i])* xs[i] for i in range(m)])

    theta0_temp = theta0 - learning_rate2 * theta0_gradient
    theta1_temp = theta1 - learning_rate1 * theta1_gradient

    theta0 = theta0_temp
    theta1 = theta1_temp

    n_steps += 1

print(theta0)
print(theta1)

print("Error: {}".format(sum([ys[i]-theta0+theta1*xs[i] for i in range(m)])))
plt.plot(xs, ys, 'ro')
plt.axis([0, max(xs), 0, max(ys)])
my_vals = list(np.arange(0, max(xs), 0.02))
plt.plot(my_vals, map(lambda q: theta0+theta1*q, my_vals), '-bo')
plt.show()
```

Here's the resulting line using the two optimized weights: [image]

Comment: Oh I thought it might have something to do with cumulative rounding. Thanks so much

Comment: when I tested the code, it still diverged the same way. Also, when you are loading the data you do `ys.append(split[1])` but unless you modified the .csv file, it should be `split[2]` because I am trying to predict the price (third column on the csv). Here is the output I got with your code: Step #1
Theta Naught: 0
Theta One: 0
Step #2
Theta Naught: 3.170212765957447e-05
Theta One: 0.06674021276595746
...Step #18
Theta Naught: 8.606923562890784e+21
Theta One: 1.9878833724306437e+25
Step #19
Theta Naught: -3.8910518224336254e+23
Theta One: -8.986901257531138e+26
Then it goes to nan.

Comment: I'm using the data at the link location you provided (it's only two columns).  Is that not the right data? You should set up IPython and see that all of your inputs and intermediate data is correct.  I'd put the embed statement before your while loop.

Comment: I just edited it to work with the data at the new link.  The TLDR is that your learning rate was too high. Dropping it to 1e-7 fixed all the issues.  I also had to change the initial conversions to ints again.

Comment: Grab the code currently on there (I edited it 30 minutes ago). It definitely works.  The image on there now is of the new dataset you posted (see the y axis). I called your new file actual_housing_prices.csv, so you might change it back, but yeah.

Comment: I got the new code. Theta1 seems to converge around 165. However, when I increase the number of steps theta0 doesn't seem to converge (it starts at ~1 and then when I went up to 10000 steps it increased to ~9 then ~1000 when I changed steps to 100000). As well, the plotting isn't working. The error is: TypeError: object of type 'map' has no len() It is likely because map returns a generator. Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: Add list(map(..)).  That should convert it to a list and solve the issue.  I'm using Python 2.7.  

Also, as far as your other issue goes, theta0 does converge, but it takes a long time (the converged value is around 71270).  You can play with this by adjusting the learning rate for both parameters seperately.  If you change your iterations to 100,000 and your learning rate for theta1 to 1e-7 and theta0 to 1e-3, you'll see the convergence.

Add print("Error: {}".format(sum([ys[i]-theta0+theta1*xs[i] for i in range(m)]))) to the end if you'd like to compare the approaches.

Comment: Oh okay. That makes sense since the magnitude of the 2 variables is so different.

Comment: I edited in the code that shows full convergence for future readers.

Comment: Also continuing with the coursera course he mentions this issue and suggests to normalize the thetas or the data (so they are ~the same magnitude)

Comment: Yeah, there are a few algorithms out there to adaptively adjust learning rates as well.  If you're interested, see ADAM, Adagrad, RMSProp, and more.  It's a reasonably common problem.